# Django Db Utils IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'slug'")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to follow the tangowithdjango book and must add a slug to update the category table. However I'm getting an error after trying to  migrate the databases.

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models_templates.html#creating-a-details-page

I did'nt provide a default value for the slug, so Django asked me to provide one and as the book instructed I type in ''.

It's worth noticing that instead of using sqlite as in the original book I'm using mysql.

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
      views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
      likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
      slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
              self.slug = slugify(self.name)
              super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

       class Meta:
              verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

       def __unicode__(self):
              return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        url = models.URLField()
        views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

The command prompt

```
sudo python manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
   Apply all migrations: admin, rango, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying rango.0003_category_slug...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in  execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 107, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 37, in database_forwards
field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 42, in add_field
super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 411, in add_field
self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 98, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 128, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'slug'")
```

Show rango_category

```
mysql> show create table rango_category;
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| rango_category | CREATE TABLE `rango_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why have you asked the same question again?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Previous answer seemed to work but it did'nt quite solve the issue.

Comment: so you shouldn't create new question, just make comment in that answer why it is not working for you.